# ESP32 WiFi server.send(); is it exclusive to ESP328266 modules, Arduino?

Tags: esp32, wifi

Is the function server.send(); exclusive to ESP8266 modules, Arduino?  Where can I find documentation regarding the application of this function with an ESP32 module with WiFi?

Comment: the ESP32 HTTPServer library

Comment: For ESP32, the equivalent implementation is in the [WebServer library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h#L122-L125).

Comment: Thank you for your response, much appreciated!